# SVG mask with base href in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg

The SVG mask works fine in Chrome but Firefox.

So I found another way to solve it.

But when I use the base tag like `<base href="/" />` , the image tag `<image width="165px" height="150px" xlink:href="mask.png" filter="url(#maskfilter)" />` is not working.

Here is the HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<base href="/" />

<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<html>
<head>
<title>mask</title>
<style>
.masked{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    -webkit-mask-image:url("mask.png");
    -webkit-mask-size:cover;
    mask:url("#svgmask");
    background-image:url("masked.jpg");
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="masked"></div>
<svg height="0">
    <filter id="maskfilter">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0" />
    </filter>
    <mask id="svgmask">
        <image width="165px" height="150px" xlink:href="mask.png" filter="url(#maskfilter)" />
    </mask>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

The image tag doesn't work even I use absolute link.

Comment: You should not be using `base` anyway – it usually creates more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 4):

Came upon the same problem. Seems like [bug 652991](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=652991/docs/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content#Example%3a.C2.A0Masking).
`<base>` creates no problems really, it's just this specific case.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the trick , you need to convert all points generated in your svg file to ratio that is equal the point path divided by mask dimension .

For easier explaination , i have made a quick tool to help designers convert their svg into a mask that is compatible with firefox , you can see a live demo on my website ( http://www.prollygeek.com ) , for example the facebook logo , and twitter logo are just masks , and here is the tool that you can use to convert your svg to a mask:
http://prollygeek.com/svg-mask/

for example:

```
<mask id="fb"  maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
<path d="M236.626,120.827v27.295h-14.851c-4.416,0-7.225,1.204-8.63,3.612c-1.003,1.604-1.405,4.415-1.405,8.229v12.442h25.287l-3.01,27.494H211.74v79.273h-32.712v-79.273h-16.055v-27.494h16.055v-16.457c0-16.858,5.82-27.695,17.259-32.311
c5.619-2.208,10.436-2.811,15.453-2.811H236.626z"/>
```

will be turned to:

```
<mask id="fb"  maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
<path d="M0.59,0.3v0.0675h-0.035c-0.01,0-0.0175,0.0025-0.02,0.0075c-0.0025,0.0025-0.0025,0.01-0.0025,0.02v0.03h0.0625l-0.0075,0.0675H0.5275v0.1975h-0.08v-0.1975h-0.04v-0.0675h0.04v-0.04c0-0.04,0.0125-0.0675,0.0425-0.08c0.0125-0.005,0.025-0.005,0.0375-0.005H0.59z" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#ffffff;"/>
```

Please dont forget to add this attribute style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#ffffff;"

and fill with any color , it doesnt matter.

afterwards link your mask to the css element you desire:

for example:

```
  mask:url(images/fb.svg#fb);
```

the calculator is free to use , but please dont copy or publish anywhere else.

**[Working Example (test on FF)](https://fiddle.jshell.net/g78ogndb/1/)**